# Portable way of optimizing a single function or TU by a specific flag in both GCC and Clang

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, clang, pragma

GCC provides two ways of optimizing a function or TU with a specific optimization flag:

```cpp
[[gnu::optimize("-ffast-math")]]
void foo() { /* ... */ }
```

```cpp
#pragma GCC optimize("ffast-math")
void foo() { /* ... */ }
```

I have checked the Clang documentation, and it seems that only a way to either completely disable optimization for a function is provided (`[[clang::optnone]]`), or a way to control whether *any* optimization is enabled or disabled via `#pragma clang optimize [on/off]`.

**Is there a way to optimize a function or TU with a specific optimization flag in Clang, similarly to what GCC offers?**